# Filling a Nav Bar with an image

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to completely fill a nav bar with my own image. The image I created is 44 by 320 pixels, which I believe is the size of the nav bar. I use the code below to put the image in the nav bar.  This works fine, but the image does not completely fill the space.  It is filled vertically, but there are a few pixels on each side (both left and right) that are not filled and the default nav bar can be seen.  Why is the image not filling the space?

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavTitle.png"];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

This has [been discussed pretty thoroughly before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432596/custom-background-for-uinavigationbar-problems).