# Category on UINavigationBar - only for certain controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, categories

I successfully implemented a navigation bar with custom background following the answer posted at [Custom background for UINavigationBar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432596/custom-background-for-uinavigationbar-problems).

However, I would like to have the standard navigation bar for some of my controllers and I have no clue how I can achieve this.

If I start a new project based on the Navigation-based Application template and just add the UINavigationBar category in separate .h and .m files, this category is applied immediately. No includes or whatever are necessary. How does this work?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: As @deanWombourne pointed out, the easiest solution is to write a subclass instead of a category and in my case this is a valid solution. However, I still would like to understand the nature of categories and why my UINavigationBar category is automatically applied to every navigation bar in my xib file. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick hack - use the tag property of your navigation bar to turn on the custom code i.e.

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if (tag < 500) {
        // Drawing code 
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"navbar_background.png"];
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.frame.size.height), img.CGImage);
    } else {
        // Do the default drawing
    }
}
@end
```

Now, navigation controllers with a tag less than 500 use your custom background. If you set the tag to be > 500, you get the default behaviour.

---

EDIT

As @MikeWeller correctly pointed out, we don't have access to the initial implementation of drawRect, our category has overridden it.

Take a look at [this link](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/supersequent-implementation.html) for a solution - basically, it's a macro that you can include that gives you an extra method :

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if (tag < 500) {
        // Drawing code 
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"navbar_background.png"];
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.frame.size.height), img.CGImage);
    } else {
        // Do the default drawing
        invokeSupersequent(rect);
    }
}
@end
```

NB I haven't tried this myself but have used other articles from this blog before with great success so I trust it :) Let us know how you get on!

Comment: The problem is there is no way to access the original drawRect implementation if you have overridden it with a category method. This is where you need to use method swizzling instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. In my case I've solved it with a subclass instead of a category. But I now I also know about method swizzling :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if (tag < 500) {
        // Drawing code 
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"navbar_background.png"];
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.frame.size.height), img.CGImage);
    } else {
        // Do the default drawing
    }
}
@end
```

Remeber this method will not work in iOS 5.0 because apple has changed the implementation of UINavigationBar so instead create a subclass of UINavigationBar and override the method there instead of creating category.

Comment: I didn't know that - do you have a link to more details of the change?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Perhaps a subclass is the right way to go (assuming that the OP can access the code that creates the UINavigationController (i.e. it's in a xib and he an set the class name) - if it's created already then a category is his only option).